# jQuery event not being triggered the second time because of another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image-gallery

This is my first post here. I am new in jQuery and I am trying to make a web gallery. The problem is with some bullet images I have under the slider, which show the current image on display.
This is the jQuery code that generates the bullets:

```
function updateProgress() {
    var txt = "";
    for(i=1;i<$slides.length;i++) // Here $slides is a jQuery object;
    {
        if(i != currentSlide)
            txt += '<img src="Images/empty_dot.png" class="dot" data-dot-id="'+i+'" />';
        else
            txt += '<img src="Images/full_dot.png" data-dot-id="'+i+'" />';
    }
    $("#progress").html(txt);
}
```

And if I inspect the element, it looks like this:

```
<div id="progress">
    <img src="Images/full_dot.png" class="dot" data-dot-id="1" />
    <img src="Images/empty_dot.png" class="dot" data-dot-id="2" />
    <img src="Images/empty_dot.png" class="dot" data-dot-id="3" />
    <img src="Images/empty_dot.png" class="dot" data-dot-id="4" />
</div>
```

Then, the callback that isn't triggered is this:

```
$(".dot").on("click",gotoImage);
```

And the gotoImage function:

```
function gotoImage() {
    var imgId = $(this).attr("data-dot-id");
    var go_to = 1000*(imgId-1)*-1;
    if(imgId == 1) go_to = 0;
    $slider.css('margin-left',go_to);
    currentSlide = imgId;
    updateProgress();
    //alert(currentSlide);
}
```

I tested this function to see which line prevent it from being called, and I found that it's because of updateProgress(), shown earlier. Also, I added the alert() in order to see when is that function called.

As my page is loaded, I call the updateProgress() once to display the bullets. Then, if I call it again, in any circumstance, the .on('click',function(){}) event won't work anymore.

So, to make it simpler: I load the page, the updateProgress() is called after loading, then I click on one of the dots (so the updateProgress() is called again). After this happens, the click event won't work.

Can you explain me why? I just can't figure out...

Here is a fiddle of the whole page: https://jsfiddle.net/antonioo/49gzp3n0/1/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to [attach the event on the parent element](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$("#progress").on("click", ".dot", gotoImage);
```

This way, clicking elements added after `.on` bubble up the DOM tree to the `#progress` element and result in `gotoImage` being called.

---

Conceptually, instead of re-building the HTML every time the current active element changes, you can just change the `src` attribute of the images:

```
function updateProgress() {
  $('.dot').each(function (index, image) {
    var dotImage = (index == currentSlide) ? 'full_dot.png' : 'empty_dot.png';
    $(image).attr('src', 'Images/' + dotImage);
  });
}
```

Or just change the `src` attribute for dot image that was *selected before*  and the one *selected now*:

```
function gotoImage() {
  var imgId = $(this).attr("data-dot-id");
  var go_to = 1000*(imgId-1)*-1;
  if (imgId == 1) go_to = 0;
  $slider.css('margin-left', go_to);
  // lines below changed
  $('.dot').eq(currentSlide || 0).attr('src', 'Images/empty_dot.png');
  currentSlide = imgId;
  $(this).attr('src', 'Images/full_dot.png');
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked just fine! I will also consider your alternatives.